# Can I change the background of a deployed object?

Tags: style, wolfram-cloud, deployment

I am deploying an object that displays some graphics.

The background of the graphics is white, and I like it that way, but it clashes with the grey background of the wolfram cloud website. Follow [this link](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/a1cca448-8070-405d-b625-f81e9671a48d) to see what I am talking about.

Is there a command I can enter in the CloudDeploy[ ] code to make the background of page white (just like a notebook)?